# Using AsyncTask to update my UI (Android)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a long running code which parses an XML and updates some TextView on my UI, the code works well but I need to put it in an AsyncTask, I'm quite new to Android and I've attempted to do this but it didn't work. Can someone please tell me what I've done wrong.

```
class UpdaterThread extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(
                    "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Cardiff");

            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            WeatherHandler myWeatherHandler = new WeatherHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myWeatherHandler);

            xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));

        }

        catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        SetWeather mySetWeather = new SetWeather();
        temp.setText(mySetWeather.getTemp());
        wind.setText(mySetWeather.getWind());
        humidity.setText(mySetWeather.getHumidity());
    }

}
```

I've also use the .execute() method in my main class to run it.

Comment: you mean you tried something like this ? UpdaterThread ut = new UpdaterThread (); ut.execute(null, null);

Comment: yes something like that, but without the null, null

Comment: Consider: class UpdaterThread extends AsyncTask<Url, String, SetWeather>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things I immediately noticed that could be wrong or not what you intended:

1. Normally you'd want to return the value obtained from `doInBackground()` for use in `onPostExecute()`, but you are returning null, which is then being passed in as the result. Is this what you want?
2. Based on that question, you'll need to change the AsyncTask types to something more fitting. Since you're simply returning `null`, setting the second type to `String` works for now, but if you return a new value, you'll need to update this type. The second type should probably be `Void` anyway, since that is the convention for unused types (since you don't implement `onProgressUpdate()`).

More background on what you're hoping to accomplish along with sample code would be helpful to figuring out the problem as well.

Comment: Let me try to explain better, I have a handler class which does the parsing work on the xml document, I have another class to store the values from the parsed xml. From my main activity I can call the setText and getvalues methods to retrieve the values and display them on the UI. This has been working perfectly. Now I need to put all this into a Thread and since threads cannot update UI I am using AsyncTask.

Comment: Do I still need to have the Aysnc return any values? This code starts the parser which will pass the file to the handler, the handler retrieves the values and passes them into another class. Is it not possible to get those values directly from the class where they are stored?

Comment: If it worked before, it should work in the same manner in the AsyncTask. The AsyncTask should not need to return any values if you are storing them elsewhere. Your code is confusing since you create a new SetWeather instance then immediately try to get values from it. Are those values being grabbed/stored from outside the SetWeather class? Or is that a mistake?

Comment: The Async class is used as an inner class of my main activity, the values are being stored in a seperate class SetWeather, I had to create an object of the class so I could use the methods to get the which were stored there. Like I said I'm quite new to Android so if I've done it wrongly i appreciate a correction

Comment: I can't use file upload sites at work, but I can check tonight. I suspect the problem comes from what you just said though. You can't create a new object and expect it to hold your pre-defined values from another instance of the object. You need to be using the same class object instance if you are storing updated values inside the class.

Comment: Thanks for the clue Matt, I sorted it out

Answer (score 0):

Two for the price of one: the AsyncTask question at [android AsyncTask xml parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806161/android-asynctask-xml-parsing/5806402#5806402) gives you some context for XML parsing using an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
SetWeather mySetWeather = new SetWeather();
        temp.setText(mySetWeather.getTemp());
```

Where do you add the parsed information to the new object created above?

What is temp? Where is it defined?

Second, personally i prefer a callback to the activity sending the new object, and then in the activity change the UI, but this is a personal preference.

Comment: they are defined in the main class, I used the AsyncTask as an inner class. temp is a textView, SetWeather is another class where I have getters and setters for my variables

Comment: Let me try to explain better, I have a handler class which does the parsing work on the xml document, I have another class to store the values from the parsed xml. From my main activity I can call the setText and getvalues methods to retrieve the values and display them on the UI. This has been working perfectly. Now I need to put all this into a Thread and since threads cannot update UI I am using AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to simultaneously update two UI while getting the progress smoothly? SOmetimes it renders extremely bad performamnce in terms of download speed and UI notification handler not responsive unless adding a thread.sleep();