# Whenever I am running my android app, it says "XYZ is not responding"

Tags: java, android

It was running perfectly fine till yesterday... I am new to android programming , Any help would be great..
In my app I am parsing a downloaded xml file and then creating a dynamic UI...
Here is a snippet of my code..

```
private class ParseXML extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Document>{

    public void onPostExecute(Document d) {


        ParseDocument(d); }



    @Override
protected Document doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     DocumentBuilderFactory dbf= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    try {
        //Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.xml_parser/raw/options");
        InputStream is=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.options);

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        dom=db.parse(is);
        Log.i(TAG,"parsing done");

    }

    catch(ParserConfigurationException pce){
        pce.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(SAXException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dom;


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is , you are trying to parse a XML in your Main UI thread. This means that you are restricting the user from performing actions with the UI. And in Andorid it is to be noted that, whenever a application doesn't respond for more the 5 seconds you will be throwed with Applicaation Not Responding Dialog.

So what you have to do is, use AsyncTask to parse your XML and then update your Ui from it.

Here is a example ,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5806402/603744

AsyncTask contains three methods namely,

1. doInBackground -which is equivalent to your Thread.
2. onPostExcecute-Called once doInBackground completes its Task.
3. onPreExecute-Called before doInBackground gets Called.

The 2nd and 3rd methods are related to UI, and you can perform any UI based actions here, and 1st method is your Background thread where you have to do your Immense Calculations, thus not affecting your UI.

Comment: there is one more thing which i wanna ask can u pls tell me how to execute this asyncTask and how to use the returned Doc parameter...

Comment: i got the basics, but there is a problem while using the returned parameter "in this case -"parsedXML""... it is always giving null , when i am using it in PostExecute(Document d);

Comment: pls look into the above code, at PostExecute its giving a java null pointer exception in ParseDocument(d);

Comment: Check the object for null in your DoInabckground before returning it. It might be null..